# what is "this._processor is null" error on firebug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firebug

I get the following error on firebug:

```
this._processor is null
```

and the error is from the file below, it seems like a default component of Firefox but i don't know what it is for either.

```
file:///Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/components/nsLivemarkService.js
```

it appears after a while when my application is idle. Do you know what might cause this error, or what this file is for?

Thanks, Sinan

PS. It's a simple filetree application, i use jquery for it, so it can be related to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's FireFox's JavaScript component responsible for fetching your feed items. If you're disturbed by it, you can open that file, wrap that line in a try/catch block and you're done with it.

Comment: ok, i get it now. It doesn't disturb me but i wanted to know if i do something wrong. Thanks.